# Filling in a table in the range between "L00000000" and "L00000010" in an oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I need help. I was once helped with a code to populate a table in the range between the first and last values. This code works fine, but there is one problem I can't figure out.

When I use as finite numbers like  `P1_FIRST = L4819222` and `P1_LAST = L4819225`, everything works fine. But when I use extreme chills as `L00000000` and `L00000010`, I get: `L1, L2, L3` ... but I wanted to see: `L00000000, L00000001, L00000002, etc.

Can you help me in this?

```
INSERT INTO test2 (val)
SELECT    SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, 1, 1)
      || TO_CHAR (
            (  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, '\d+$'))
             + LEVEL
             - 1))
         AS val
 FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_LAST, '\d+$'))
             - TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR
```

Comment: That is because 00000000 < 1 < 2 < 0000000010 if you treat them as numbers.

Comment: SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, 1, 1) || LPAD(TO_CHAR ( ( TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, '\d+$')) + LEVEL - 1)), 8,'0')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SQL> select 'L' || lpad(level - 1, 8, '0') val
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 11;

VAL
---------
L00000000
L00000001
L00000002
L00000003
L00000004
L00000005
L00000006
L00000007
L00000008
L00000009
L00000010

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As of INSERT and Apex items:

```
SQL> create table test (val varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (val)
  2  with subs as
  3    (select to_number(regexp_substr('&P1_LAST' , '\d+$')) clast,
  4            to_number(regexp_substr('&P1_FIRST', '\d+$')) cfirst
  5     from dual
  6    )
  7  select 'L' || lpad(cfirst + level - 1, 8, '0') val
  8  from subs
  9  connect by level <= clast - cfirst + 1;
Enter value for p1_last: L4819225
Enter value for p1_first: L4819222

4 rows created.

SQL> /
Enter value for p1_last: L0000010
Enter value for p1_first: L0000000

11 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test order by val;

VAL
--------------------
L00000000
L00000001
L00000002
L00000003
L00000004
L00000005
L00000006
L00000007
L00000008
L00000009
L00000010
L04819222
L04819223
L04819224
L04819225

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Query you'll use in Apex is

```
insert into test (val)
with subs as
  (select to_number(regexp_substr(:P1_LAST , '\d+$')) clast,
          to_number(regexp_substr(:P1_FIRST, '\d+$')) cfirst
   from dual
  )          
select 'L' || lpad(cfirst + level - 1, 8, '0') val
from subs
connect by level <= clast - cfirst + 1;
```

Comment: i am trying to merge these two codes, but i am constantly making a mistake:INSERT INTO test2 (val)
SELECT
SUBSTR ('L00000000', 1, 1)
      || TO_CHAR (
            (  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR ('L00000000', '\d+$', lpad(level - 1, 8, '0'))
             + LEVEL
             - 1))
         AS val
 FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR ('L00000010', '\d+$'))
             - TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR ('L00000000', '\d+$'))
             + 1;

Comment: I've added some more examples. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You need using LPAD. Try:

```
SELECT SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, 1, 1)
      ||
 LPAD(TO_CHAR (  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, '\d+$')) + level), 8,'0') AS val 
FROM dual
connect by level < 10:
```

in your case:

```
SELECT SUBSTR ('L00000000', 1, 1) || lpad(TO_CHAR (  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR ('L00000000', '\d+$' )) + LEVEL - 1), 8, '0') AS val 
FROM dual 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_NUMBER ( REGEXP_SUBSTR ('L00000010', '\d+$')) - TO_NUMBER ( REGEXP_SUBSTR ('L00000000', '\d+$')) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand this code so it will only be relevant for a number of 8 characters ??

Comment: Yes. It's in current case, in current pattern. If you write more information, decision will be universal.